# A ring R is an algebra iff the ambient space $X$ is in R

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$(Def):$ A family $\mathcal{R} \subset \mathcal{P}(X) $ is a $\sigma-$ring if it is closed under countable unions and if $E,F \in \mathcal{R}, $then $E \setminus F \in \mathcal{R} $.

$(Def): $ $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{P}(X) $ is a $\sigma-$algebra if it is closed under countable unions and if $E \in \mathcal{A} $, then $E^c = X \setminus E \in \mathcal{A} $

$(Hw Prob)$: Let $\mathcal{R} $ be a $\sigma-$ring of sets on $X$. Show that $\mathcal{R} $ is a $\sigma-$algebra iff $X \in \mathcal{R} $

#### TRY:

Suppose $\mathcal{R} $ is $\sigma-$ring. if $\mathcal{R} $ is a sigma algebra, then we have $X = E \cup E^c \in \mathcal{R} $.

Conversely, suppose $X \in \mathcal{R} $. We must show $\mathcal{R} $ is a $\sigma-$algebra. Indeed, if $E \in \mathcal{R}$, then since $X \in \mathcal{R}$, we must have that $X \setminus E \in \mathcal{R} $ since $\mathcal{R} $ is a ring.

Is this enough for the solution?

Comment: Yes, I think that's enough.

Comment: You forgot to mention one essential part: a [$\sigma$-ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-ring) is not allowed to be empty. So some $E\in\mathcal R$ *exists*. Then the conclusion $X=E\cup E^c\in\mathcal R$ can be made. Secondly also $\sigma$-algebras are not allowed to be empty so your definitions of $\sigma$-ring and $\sigma$-algebra are not complete.